# How to find the ec2 instance id by passing volume id using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I want to pass the volume id as a parameter which then returns the instance id in python

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call `describe_instances()`.

You can either filter the results yourself in Python, or pass `Filters` for `block-device-mapping.volume-id`.

```
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = ec2_client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name':'block-device-mapping.volume-id','Values':['vol-deadbeef']}])

instance_id = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']

print(instance_id)
```

A volume can only be attached to one instance at a time, so this code assumes only one instance is returned.

Comment: You can also perform an API call for DescribeVolumes that returns you the Attachment information which has the InstanceID.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rajesh pointed out, an easier way is to use `DescribeVolumes`, which returns `Attachment` information:

```
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = ec2_client.describe_volumes(VolumeIds=['vol-deadbeef'])

print(response['Volumes'][0]['Attachments'][0]['InstanceId'])
```

This code assumes that the instance is the first attachment on the volume (since EBS volumes can only be attached to one instance).